# Page combinations in BigQuery's Google Analytics data

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Using Google Analytics data in Google BigQuery, I can derive the number of sessions that include a hit on the /confirm/ page with:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT date AS Date, COUNT(Date) AS Sessions
FROM (
  SELECT date
  FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_20161202`
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) as hit
  WHERE hit.type = 'PAGE' AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '/confirm/$')
  GROUP BY VisitId, fullVisitorId, date
)
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date ASC, Sessions ASC;
```

How about if I wanted to show the number of sessions that hit *both* the /confirm/ page and the /payment/ page? What should my SQL look like?

Comment: ORing the WHERE clause, similar to Paul's suggestion below. ANDing it, which of course produces nothing, as no single hit has two pathPaths. Lots of other trial and error stuff. Unfortunately my SQL is very rusty. Looking at self joins at the moment, but unsure if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below, should give you an idea

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE, COUNT(1) AS Sessions
FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_20161202`
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hit WHERE hit.type = 'PAGE' 
                 AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '/confirm/$') ) > 0
AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hit WHERE hit.type = 'PAGE' 
                 AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '/payment/$') ) > 0
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE ASC, Sessions ASC;
```

Above can be further optimized as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE, COUNT(1) AS Sessions
FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_20161202`
WHERE (SELECT COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '/confirm/$')) *
          COUNTIF(REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '/payment/$'))
        FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hit WHERE hit.type = 'PAGE') > 0
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE ASC, Sessions ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to do this is to use a single subquery in the `WHERE` clause that checks for both hit types. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE, COUNT(*) AS Sessions
FROM `123456789.ga_sessions_20161202`
WHERE ((SELECT COUNTIF(hit.page.pagePath LIKE '%confirm/$') > 0 AND
          COUNTIF(hit.page.pagePath LIKE '%/payment/$%') > 0
        FROM UNNEST(hits) AS hit WHERE hit.type = 'PAGE'))
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE ASC, Sessions ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, assuming a Regex

```
 WHERE hit.type = 'PAGE' AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '(/confirm/$)|(/payment/$)')
```

Comment: Hi Paul, That gives me sessions that hit *either* /confirm/, /payment/ or both. I'm after both only.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this query in our `GA` dataset and it might work for you:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
date,
COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fv, CAST(v AS string))) sessions
FROM(
  SELECT 
  date,
  fullvisitorid fv,
  visitid v,
  CASE WHEN (MAX(CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '/confirm/$') THEN TRUE END) AND MAX(CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '/payment/$') THEN TRUE END)) THEN TRUE END flag
  FROM `dafiti-analytics.40663402.ga_sessions_20170102`,
  UNNEST(hits) hit
  WHERE 1 = 1
  AND hit.type = 'PAGE' AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, r'/confirm/$|/payment/$')
  GROUP BY fv, v, date
  HAVING flag IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY 
    date
```

So first thing is that I selected all users and their sessions that contained either **confirm** or **payment** in their `hits.page.pagepath` field.

After that, I used the `MAX` operation and grouped by the visitors and their sessions to find when both `confirm` and `payment` happened, like so:

```
 CASE WHEN (MAX(CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '/confirm/$') THEN TRUE END) AND MAX(CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(hit.page.pagePath, '/payment/$') THEN TRUE END)) THEN TRUE END flag
```

`flag` is true when a given visitor on a given session had both `confirm` and `payment` in their navigation.

And then just `COUNT DISTINCT` the concatenation of visitors and their sessions to get total sessions (this is so because the `visitid` is not unique among visitors).