# Extract user journey data between two pages in BigQuery Google Analytics data

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

How to extract users' journey data between two specific pages in Google Analytics BigQuery Export data?

**Example:**

Website has 100 pages: `hits.page.pagePath=/page_1` to `hits.page.pagePath=/page_100`.

Goal is to extract user journey data from `/page_13` to `/page_22`, including all in-between pages.

The challenge is that the journey is not sequential, like `/page_13` -> `/page14` -> `...` -> `/page_22`.

But could be `/page13` -> `/page_5` -> `/page_41` -> `/page_99` -> `/page_22`.

Comment: Please show some sample data.

Comment: It's similar to Google's Google Analytics sample dataset in BigQuery.

`SELECT
  DISTINCT page.pagePath
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`,
  UNNEST(hits)
limit 100;`

Let's say user journey from `/store.html` to `/basket.html`. In between user may have viewed `/google+redesign/apparel/womens/womens+outerwear`, `/google+redesign/wearables/men+s+t-shirts/home` or `/google+redesign/bags/backpacks/google+laptop+tech+backpack+black.axd`. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_agg()`.  If I understand correctly, you want a group to being when it first hits page_13 and end when it hits page_22.

Let me assume that for each user you want the *first* hit of 13 to the *first* hit of 22.  You can identify the group by these two characteristics:

```
select h.*
from (select h.*,
             countif( page like '%/page_13' ) over (partition by user order by hit_time) as hit_13,
             countif( page like '%/page_22' ) over (partition by user order by hit_time) as hit_22,
             countif( page like '%/page_22' ) over (partition by user) as has_22
      from hits h
     ) h
where has_22 and
      hit_13 > 0 and
      (hit_22 = 0 or page like '%/page_22);
```

This returns the pages that start with 13, end with 22 and ensure that users have both.

Now for the journey, just use aggregate.  But, alas, BQ does not allow aggregation on arrays -- if you subsequently want to summarize by the journeys.  So, I'll use `string_agg()` instead:

```
select h.user,
       string_agg(page order by hit_time, ' -> ')
from (select h.*
      from (select h.*,
                   countif( page like '%/page_13' ) over (partition by user order by hit_time) as hit_13,
                   countif( page like '%/page_22' ) over (partition by user order by hit_time) as hit_22,
                   countif( page like '%/page_22' ) over (partition by user) as has_22
            from hits h
           ) h
      where has_22 and
            hit_13 > 0 and
            (hit_22 = 0 or page like '%/page_22)
     ) h
group by user;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time on this!

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics sample [dataset](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=bigquery-public-data&d=google_analytics_sample&t=ga_sessions_20170801&page=table) has a cookbook with some examples such as  the *Sequence of hits* one [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694). Using `STRING_AGG(hits.page.pagePath)` you can build the desired `userJourney` sequence of hits.

To filter only the two desired pages we could use an approach such as the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463338/page-combinations-in-bigquerys-google-analytics-data). However, in our case we want to set one as the `origin` and the other one as the `destination`. In addition we can cut once the user has reached the target page so that both these paths are analogous:

`/page13` -> `/page_5` -> `/page_41` -> `/page_99` -> `/page_22`

`/page13` -> `/page_5` -> `/page_41` -> `/page_99` -> `/page_22` -> `page_37`

Also note that we can use the new [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) feature, currently in Beta, to be able to change the page pairs at the top of the script and build a dynamic regex. As an example to check journey between `/home` and `/google+redesign/shop+by+brand/youtube` using the available public data:

```sql
#standardSQL
-- Script to change origin and destination pages with dynamic regex.
DECLARE origin, destination, regex STRING;

SET origin = '/home';
SET destination = '/google+redesign/shop+by+brand/youtube';
SET regex = CONCAT('(', REPLACE(origin, '+', '\\+'), '.*?', REPLACE(destination, '+', '\\+'), ')');

-- Run query
SELECT
  pagePath AS userJourney,
  COUNT(1) AS frequency
FROM (
  SELECT
    visitId,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(STRING_AGG(hits.page.pagePath), regex) AS pagePath
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701'
    AND '20170731'
    AND hits.type="PAGE"
  GROUP BY
    visitId)
WHERE
  pagePath IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  pagePath
ORDER BY
  COUNT(1) DESC
LIMIT
  10
```

Which returns the following result:

[image]

To further optimize it we could select only the last occurrence of the `origin` but maybe you want to count things such as these as different paths:

`/page13` -> `/page_99` -> `/page_22`

`/page13` -> `/page_5` -> `/page_13` -> `/page_99` -> `/page_22`

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed answer, it really helps. I'll wait for general availability as the script needs to run in prod.